# Twilio retrieve SMS logs with pagination information

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am new to Twilio uses. I want to retrieve all message logs with paging information. Is the read API sufficient for that, or do I have to use next page API also? Please guide me with parameters I need to pass to get 10 per page.

```
var accountSid = "xxx";                   
var authToken = "yyy";    
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

var messages = MessageResource.Read(limit: 2);

MessageResource.NextPage()
```

How to fill parameter in `Page<MessageResource>` page in NextPage API?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the [`pageSize` parameter](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageResource.cs#L331) to set how many messages you receive per page.

```
var accountSid = "xxx";                   
var authToken = "yyy";    
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

var messages = MessageResource.Read(pageSize: 2);

MessageResource.NextPage()
```

Comment: MessageResource.NextPage(); doesn't work as it expects a parameter

Comment: How does this work if I'm calling this from an API?  what if I want page 2 specifically with all records?  What constitutes a page?